# Show 'Unknown' for Null Ids in SQL

Tags: sql

when the numeric field is Null how to show a string value? Tried the syntax below but getting an error

> 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric':

Syntax:

```
select 
case 
when bill_area_id IS null then 'Unknown'
else bill_area_id end  from Table_name
```

Comment: `select coalesce(bill_area_id, 'Unkown') from tablename`, note that same data type is required.

Comment: Note that these types of decisions are usually done in the _display_ layer, meaning the web page, app, report, whatever, rather than the _data_ layer.

Comment: Since the answer over there is DBMS-agnostic, this is a duplicate of [Displaying NULL values as 'unknown' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092603/displaying-null-values-as-unknown-is-sql-server) or probably many other questions asking for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce` to return first non-null value :

```
select coalesce(bill_area_id, 'Unknown') from Table_name
```

Note that compatible data types is required. I.e. you may have to do :

```
select coalesce(cast(bill_area_id as varchar(15)), 'Unknown') from Table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sql server`, you can also use this :

```
select isnull(cast(bill_area_id as varchar(15)), 'Unknown') from Table_name
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Well, i believe what he tried already works for MySQL. Not sure about `Oracle`, but seeing the provided error message, i think this is ms sql server issue. Anyway better to specify it in the answer, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are mixing varchar with numeric output in the same column. For SQL Server for example:

```
select 
case 
when bill_area_id IS null then 'Unknown'
else CAST(bill_area_id as varchar) end  from Table_name
```

Ensures that the output is uniformly varchar since I am casting bill_area_id as varchar, or selecting 'Unknown' (also a varchar).

There are other answers here using COALESCE/isnull that are just as valid, since those functions provide an alternative to NULL values.